# Circles on start and end of range slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i want to make a range slider with some design in it. I have no idea how to stylize the input. http://prntscr.com/ebyoev like this one
The thing i want to do is, i dont know how to implement the circles on the start and end of the range slider and how to stylize the current circle range

https://jsfiddle.net/agghvm9t/ this is the fiddle

This is how far i have come

```
<div class="range-slider">
  <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="100" min="0" max="500">
</div>
```

This is my css

```
 *, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 60px 20px;
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  body {
    padding: 60px;
  }
}

.range-slider {
  margin: 60px 0 0 0%;
}

.range-slider {
  width: 100%;
}

.range-slider__range {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: calc(100% - (73px));
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d7dcdf;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.range-slider__range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2c3e50;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background .15s ease-in-out;
  transition: background .15s ease-in-out;
}
.range-slider__range::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
  background: #1abc9c;
}
.range-slider__range:active::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: #1abc9c;
}
.range-slider__range::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2c3e50;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background .15s ease-in-out;
  transition: background .15s ease-in-out;
}
.range-slider__range::-moz-range-thumb:hover {
  background: #1abc9c;
}
.range-slider__range:active::-moz-range-thumb {
  background: #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__value {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #2c3e50;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-left: 8px;
}
.range-slider__value:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: -7px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid #2c3e50;
  border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
  content: '';
}

::-moz-range-track {
  background: #d7dcdf;
  border: 0;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-outer {
  border: 0;
}
```

THis is my jquery

```
    var rangeSlider = function(){
  var slider = $('.range-slider'),
      range = $('.range-slider__range'),
      value = $('.range-slider__value');

  slider.each(function(){

    value.each(function(){
      var value = $(this).prev().attr('value');
      $(this).html(value);
    });

    range.on('input', function(){
      $(this).next(value).html(this.value);
    });
  });
};

rangeSlider();
```

Comment: Provide a working example snippet or fiddle.

Comment: yes provide a working link of example

Comment: I updated the question, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd approach this with using pseudo elements. You can have one :before and one :after pseudo element and since you only need two - one at the beginning and one at the end, it might just work:

```
.range-slider {
    position:relative;
}
.range-slider:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url("circle-image");
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}
.range-slider:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background-image: url("circle-image");
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

To style the sliding circle, you can try something like this:

```
.range-slider__range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: orange;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background .15s ease-in-out;
  transition: background .15s ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 6px #fff;
}
```

Comment: That works, and maybe you have idea how to stylize the sliding circle? thanks in advance

Comment: Extended my answer to include styling the circle too.